# what is the meaning of 0x0? say when variable gets assigned to it, example: keccak256(number) = 0x0;

Tags: solidity, remix

Is 0x0 just zero? thanks

```
keccak256(number) = 0x0;
```

Or when not used as address I mean just to denote variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0x` prefix means hexadecimal and it's a way to tell programs, contracts, APIs that the input should be interpreted as a hexadecimal number (we'll shorten to hex). `0x0` is actually `0` but in hex. Usually we use `0x0` to check whether the address is not set by us and it is set to default value by the solidity which is 0x0.

`require(_addressIn != address(0))`

E.g. `0x0` in Solidity is short for `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, and if we use this as some address than it does have value greater than zero. check [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000).

`Keccak256` computes the Ethereum-SHA-3 (Keccak-256) hash ([doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html)) of the arguments passed into the function. So the above line of code is not correct because `keccak256(number)` is returning the hash value which you can store in some variable, instead you are trying to treat the output hash value as an variable and assigning the `0x0` to that.

I hope it helps.

Comment: "0x0 in Solidity is short for 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" I guess technically that's true, just like in decimal, 0 is short for 0000000000 (for any number of 0s). But I think it's misleading to say that, as it makes people think it represents some special value or some specific type. It just means `0`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this: "Usually we use 0x0 to check whether the address is not set by us and it is set to default value by the solidity which is 0x0." So at a high level, require(_addressIn != 0x0) checks that the address was not arbitrarily set by us, and was for sure generated by the EVM? I can't step through how that works...to me that reads "if address is not 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" then throw an error so any address that's not 0x0 would pass here right? I'm misunderstanding something lol.

Answer (score 3):

The example given wouldn't actually work because you're trying to assign `0x0` to the `keccak` function.

It has the same meaning as `bytes32(0)`. So, you can go:

```
require(bytes32(0) == 0x0);
```

That would be comparing equivalents. It was possible to compare `address` and `0x0` but the trend seems to be toward explicit type casting, so you would go `address(0)` with a recent compiler.

This type of expression is often used to validate inputs, in particular, catching important values that were not passed in. This is common:

```
function doSomething(bytes32 key) ... {
  require(key != 0x0);
  // carry on
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per my view, we are just checking for the invalid receiver.

> Token.sol

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    // Go on
}
```

> token.js

```
it('Rejects invalid receiver', async() => {
   await token.transfer(0x0, amount, { from: deployer }).should.be.rejectedWith('Your message');
});
```